# Recursive CTE gives "Error at line 1/16: ORA-00905: missing keyword" error on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

I copied the above code from Oracle documentation. It works fine when I run it in MySQL, but I get the error message "Error at line 1/16: ORA-00905: missing keyword" when I run it in Oracle's Apex workshop. It is strange that a sample from Oracle documentation does not work.
Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here is the link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive   Also the same query works fine with MySQL.

Comment: mysql is not pracle

Comment: I also see this error. My statement works when I remove the RECURSIVE keyword. Oracle's documentation states that RECURSIVE is not required, but is allowed. It seems that it is not allowed. The SQL parser that IntelliJ uses for the HSQLDB dialect requires RECURSIVE in order to recognize references to the CTE (i.e. the temporary result set) in the recursive SELECT statement of a recursive CTE. Even so, the statement executes just fine without the keyword in both Oracle and HSQLDB.

Answer (score 1):

It is syntactically invalid to have `RECURSIVE` in the query. Whichever documentation you used it was not for an Oracle database; you want [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Additionally, `SELECT 1` is not valid as you have a `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause; it should be `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`.

The fixed code should be:

```sql
WITH cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Which outputs:

| N |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lm4v9Exi)

Answer (score 1):

In oralce, you can't use SELECT 1, that is only allowed in Mysql

As is aid ORACLE rdms is not Mysql RDMS

```
select * from V$VERSION;
```

| BANNER | BANNER_FULL | BANNER_LEGACY | CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production | Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 21.3.0.0.0 | Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production | 0 |

```
    WITH  cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1 FROm DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

| N |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yBqYmFYu)